# How to find the average of numbers in a generic class of Numbers in Java?

Tags: java, oop

I have created a generic class that creates an `ArrayList` of `Numbers`

```
public class MyMathClass<T extends Number> {
private ArrayList<T> myarraylist;

public MyMathClass(ArrayList<T> arrayList){
    myarraylist = arrayList;
}
```

I tried to create a method that basically calculates the average of the given ArrayList

```
public double average(){
    var average = 0;
    for(int i = 0 ; i <= myarraylist.size(); i++){
        average += myarraylist.get(i);
    }
}
```

but when try to add the average with the value at index *i*, I get this error: "operator + cannot be applied to 'int' , 'T'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Number` objects implement a `doubleValue()` method. Return the average of those:

```
public double average() {
    return myarraylist.stream().mapToDouble(Number::doubleValue).average().orElse(0);
}
```

The `orElse(0)` handles the list being empty.

---

Style note: Use the abstract type where possible, so prefer:

```
private List<T> myList;

public MyMathClass(List<T> list){
    myList = list;
}
```

See [Liskov substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).

Answer (score 1):

It's relative to Unboxed Type and Box Type.

Refer here for more detail: [What does it mean to say a type is "boxed"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1418296/what-does-it-mean-to-say-a-type-is-boxed)

To make your code work, only need to convert Number to double and sum it.

```
Number num = myarraylist.get(i);
average += num == null ? 0 : num.doubleValue();
```